# Counting down to a time?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to count down to a time of the day (24-hour clock format). This is my solution so far:

```
function TimeDiffStr(const s1, s2: string): string;
var
  t1, t2: TDateTime;
  secs: Int64;
begin
  t1 := StrToDateTime(s1);
  t2 := StrToDateTime(s2);
  secs := SecondsBetween(t1, t2);
  Result := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d', [secs div 3600, (secs div 60) mod 60, secs mod 60]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  TargetTime: TTime;
  s: string;
begin
  s := TimeDiffStr(TimeToStr(Now), TimeToStr(TargetTime));
end;
```

If `Now` is, for example, `15:35:02` and the target time is `21:44:59`, the output is correct (06:09:57). However, if `Now` is `15:35:02` and the target time is `01:32:23`, instead of counting down from 09:57:21, it will count upwards, because the function does not know that the target time is on a different day.

How can I work out the difference between two times when the times are on different days?

Comment: If the start time is less than the end time, add 24 hours to the start time

Comment: @David Thanks very much for reply! If I put `if Now < TargetTime then TargetTime := TargetTime + 24;` in to the procedure, before `s` assignment, it still counts up, instead of down. :(

Comment: Why are you passing strings around? You've got the "secs" correct, no?

Comment: Formula is not correct. `if Now < TargetTime then TargetTime := TargetTime + 24;` **must be**  `if TargetTime < Now then TargetTime := TargetTime + 24;`

Comment: Adding `+24` to a `TDateTime` adds 24 **days**, not 24 **hours**. Use `+1` to add 24 hours, aka 1 day. Or use `IncHour(TargetTime, 24)` or `IncDay(TargetTime, 1)` instead

Comment: Something like `d:=Abs(Frac(t1))-Abs(Frac(t2)); if d<0 then d:=d+1;` should calculate what you need (all variables `TDateTime`). Comparing `TTime` and `Now` is the wrong approach - one is time only and the second one is date/time. Also `+24` adds 24 days not hours.

Comment: @ShungLao123 Yeah, I said 24 hours, not 24 days

Comment: Of course there's the possibility of t2 being 2 days ahead. This is not the way to do this. You need to think this from the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

First off, there is no need to pass strings around.  If you start with `TTime` and convert to `TTime`, then simply pass `TTime` around.

Second, since you are dealing with just time values, if the target time is meant to be on the next day, you need to add 24 hours so that you have a `TDateTime` that actually represents the next day.

Try this:

```pascal
uses
  ..., DateUtils;

function TimeDiffStr(const t1, t2: TTime): string;
var
  d1, d2: TDateTime;
  secs: Int64;
begin
  d1 := t1;
  if t2 < t1 then
    d2 := IncDay(t2) // or IncHour(t2, 24)
  else
    d2 := t2; 
  secs := SecondsBetween(d1, d2);
  Result := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d', [secs div 3600, (secs div 60) mod 60, secs mod 60]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  TargetTime: TTime;
  s: string;
begin
  TargetTime := ...;
  s := TimeDiffStr(Time(), TargetTime);
end;
```